# Silverstripe 3: how to sort pages in the CMS sitetree by title, date etc

Tags: sorting, silverstripe

I'm looking for a working example of how to sort my pages in the sitetree by title by default. Ideally I only want to sort child pages of a certain type. In my case I want all my Gallery pages under the parent Portfolio to be sorted Alphabetically by their title.
This is for easy searching in the backend CMS as I know how to sort them in the template.

I have found these examples but not enough to work this out for SS3.1+

http://www.ssbits.com/tutorials/2011/custom-sorting-in-the-cms-sitetree/
https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-cms/issues/848

Comment: Sadly I don't have the time to answer directly your question but this presentation might help you [Stevie Mayhew - Little Giant - "SiteTree-less Sites or: How I learned to stop worrying and love ModelAdmin"](https://vimeo.com/119727130)

Comment: If you found my answer helpful, please mark it as accepted. That way it can signal to visitors that come across the same issue to know there are known solutions for the problem. If not, let me know what other details you want and I can chase them up. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having a look at the examples you gave and the current Silverstripe source, there is a few ways you could go about this. My solution involves using Silverstripe's extension system to manipulate how the hierarchy is generated.

#### How the [`SiteTree`](http://api.silverstripe.org/3.1/class-SiteTree.html) is loaded

The way the CMS loads the site tree is a little lengthy so I will quickly simplify:

- The template `CMSPagesController_Content.ss` (used for the pages section) has markup to lazy-load the linked tree view
- The linked tree view (a function specified in [`CMSMain`](http://api.silverstripe.org/3.1/class-CMSMain.html#_LinkTreeView)) calls a few internal methods to basically load the `CMSMain_TreeView` template
- This template calls the [`SiteTreeAsUL`](http://api.silverstripe.org/3.1/class-CMSMain.html#_SiteTreeAsUL) function back in `CMSMain`

  > Note: `SiteTreeAsUL` allows us to hook in before returning using the extension system in Silverstripe though we don't want to manipulate
  >   the HTML directly.
- [`getSiteTreeFor`](http://api.silverstripe.org/3.1/class-LeftAndMain.html#_getSiteTreeFor), a function part of [`LeftAndMain`](http://api.silverstripe.org/3.1/class-LeftAndMain.html), is called inside the `SiteTreeAsUL`.
- `getSiteTreeFor` calls [`getChildrenAsUL`](http://api.silverstripe.org/3.1/class-Hierarchy.html#_getChildrenAsUL), a function part of [`Hierarchy`](http://api.silverstripe.org/3.1/class-Hierarchy.html), which actually does the HTML building but most importantly, calls the correct "children" method.

I say correct children method as there is a few:

- [AllChildren](http://api.silverstripe.org/3.1/class-Hierarchy.html#_AllChildren)
- [AllChildrenIncludingDeleted](http://api.silverstripe.org/3.1/class-Hierarchy.html#_AllChildrenIncludingDeleted)
- [AllHistoricalChildren](http://api.silverstripe.org/3.1/class-Hierarchy.html#_AllHistoricalChildren)
- [Children](http://api.silverstripe.org/3.1/class-Hierarchy.html#_Children)

Because `getSiteTreeFor` is called without specifying the children method, [it uses a hardcoded default of `AllChildrenIncludingDeleted`](http://api.silverstripe.org/3.1/source-class-LeftAndMain.html#797-802).

#### Now, time to sort the children...

Calling the function `AllChildrenIncludingDeleted` does a few calls but what we want to know is that it internally calls the extension method [`augmentAllChildrenIncludingDeleted`](http://api.silverstripe.org/3.1/source-class-Hierarchy.html#556-558).

So, to do what you are wanting to do, you likely will want to write an extension for `SiteTree` with the extended function `augmentAllChildrenIncludingDeleted`. First argument is the list of all children which are stored as an [`ArrayList`](http://api.silverstripe.org/3.1/class-ArrayList.html).

> Technical Note: It actually can be an `ArrayList` OR [`DataList`](http://api.silverstripe.org/3.1/class-DataList.html)
>   because if there are no live children, it returns the raw result of
>   [`stageChildren`](http://api.silverstripe.org/3.1/source-class-Hierarchy.html#613-630) which is a `DataList`.
>   While both have sort functions, they may act differently.

[`ArrayList` provides a sort function](http://api.silverstripe.org/3.1/class-ArrayList.html#_sort) which would allow you to do what you were intending.

Something like this should work:

```
class CMSSiteTreeSortingExtension extends Extension
{
    public function augmentAllChildrenIncludingDeleted($Children, $Context = null)
    {
        if ($this->owner->ClassName == 'GalleryPage')
        {
            //Do your class specific sorting here....
        }

        $Children = $Children->sort('Title DESC');
    }
}
```

And just set the extension against `SiteTree` (or `Page` if you want, should still work).

*Disclaimer: I haven't personally tried this however it follows the standard pattern for how Silverstripe works with extensions so you shouldn't have a problem.*

Answer (score 2):

I've been searching for a way to achieve this in SS4 when I couldn't get the above code to work. This is what I've come up with.

```php
use SilverStripe\ORM\DB;

class MemberPage extends Page
{
    public function onAfterWrite(){
        parent::onAfterWrite();

        $pages = MemberPage::get()->sort('Title');
        $sortIndex = 0;
        foreach ($pages as $page){
            //sort indexes start at 1
            $sortIndex++;
            if ($page->Sort != $sortIndex){
                //we can't use $page->write() here, otherwise it'll cause infinite loops,
                //we'll just have to run the query on the database directly
                DB::query("UPDATE SiteTree SET Sort = {$sortIndex} WHERE ID = {$page->ID}");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It's not exactly 'the silverstripe way' but it works.